# YouTube Player Integration with chromecast

Tags: android, youtube-api, chromecast

Is it possible to cast a video from youtube SDK for android ?. Currently am playing youTube videos using videoID (not url) in player.I am using latest YouTube SDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there are no APIs available to accomplish this. Some folks, with varying degrees of success, have used the embedded (iframe) player.

Comment: Is there any documents available for integrating iframe with chromecast in android?

Comment: None that I am aware of, but basically a receiver in the cast world is simply an html + JavaScript + CSS, so you can add your things to it as you would do in a normal web application. Then you need to use the Cast SDK to send the info required by your iframe to play the content you want; note that there are limitations to this approach; for example user cannot skip ads, etc.