# Launch Youtube and auto connect to chrome cast device from application

Tags: android, youtube, chromecast

I am exploring Google ChromeCast api and i am having some questions. Is it possible to launch and auto connect Youtube application to chrome cast device from my app? I am able to connect my application with chrome cast automatically but not getting hoe to connect youtube without clicking on cast icon.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to first check [Google Cast SDK Additional Developer Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/terms#3developer-policies) wherein it was mentioned under [Developer policies](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/terms#3developer-policies) that:

> - *3.4.8*   must not automatically cast content. Content should only be cast in response to a user request to cast that content;

To connect YouTube app to Chromecast device, please check [Discovery Troubleshooting](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/discovery) wherein it was mentioned that YouTube apps uses some specialized discovery mechanisms.

Lastly, you may want to check these SO posts for additional insights and also possible options that you  may want to try:

- [YouTube Player Integration with chromecast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29850184/youtube-player-integration-with-chromecast?rq=1)
- [Android youtube sdk integration with Google chromecast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34491277/android-youtube-sdk-integration-with-google-chromecast)
- [Open Chromecast youtube video from android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23450163/open-chromecast-youtube-video-from-android-application)

Comment: This app is not going to be publish on play store. Its for my own use so i am not worried about developer polishes. I am just exploring to connect youtube app to chrome cast by direct launching from my app.